# sql skip to count row number for certain conditions

Tags: sql

I wanted to sum all records if column A is Plan1 else skip to count the row. But i don't know how to skip to count the row..Below is my query.

```
Select case when columnA='Plan1' then count(columnA) else ??(how to skip to count the row) end from tableA
```

Exp:

```
    No Column A
    1  Plan1
    2  Plan1
    3  Plan3
    4  Plan1
```

answer: 3

Comment: Give table definitions, sample data and wanted result.

Comment: And if there was another record `5 Plan2` for example would the result you are looking for be `8`?  I.E a sum of `no` where `Column A` does not equal `Plan1`  Is that what you are looking for? I think you need to be a little clearer on what you actually want as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   tablea
WHERE  columna = 'Plan1'
```

Alternative solution:

```
SELECT Count(*) As total
     , Sum(CASE WHEN columna = 'Plan1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As plan1
FROM   tablea
```